# ASP.NET Repeater need to alter display

Tags: asp.net

I have the following Repeater:

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpttsk" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>ID</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>Date</b>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("ID")%>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("PerfDate", "{0:MMM d, yyyy}")%>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I am putting the code in the code behind file

```
     Protected Sub rpttsk_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpttsk.ItemDataBound
```

but not even hitting this sub procedure

Comment: about not hitting the sub procedure. Did you make sure to do this in your front end?

<asp:Repeater ID="rpttsk" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpttsk_ItemDataBound">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:
Frontend:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpttsk" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpttsk_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>ID</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Date</b>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("ID")%>
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"/>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Backend:

```
protected void rpttsk_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        YourDataType item = e.Item.DataItem as YourDataType;
        Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lbl") as Label;
        lbl.Text = item;
        if (DateTime.Compare(item.YourDateHere, DateTime.Now()) > 0)
        {
            lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want entire rows to be coloured, you'll have to put everything in labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this logic in code Behind in ItemDataBound

```
void rpttsk_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: are you missing the `Access Modifier`? Should it be `Protected`?

Comment: just sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx, but Thank's RGI for your help

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the colour to display is a view concern. In general I would put view concern logic into the views rather than the code behinds. It allows for more view flexibility. It can make maintenance easier since cosmetic updates to your applications don't require as many binary updates.

You could technically say that the logic of comparing the date to today is a business logic concern, possibly. So that could be a code behind thing, such as a getter like "IsDateGreaterThanToday".

Then your repeater view could be revised like so:

```
<td <%# IsViewGreaterThanToday(Eval("PerfDate")) ? "class='greater-than-today'" : ""%>>
<%#Eval("PerfDate", "{0:MMM d, yyyy}")%>
</td>
```